# Convert hex string to binary SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server
I want To Convert this Value :
**20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0**

> ( Column Type Is NVARCHAR(MAX) )

To This Value :
**0x20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0**

> ( Column Type Is Binary(16) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    nvar nvarchar(max),
    bin16 binary(16)
)

INSERT INTO @test (nvar) VALUES
(N'20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0')

UPDATE @test
SET bin16 = CONVERT(binary(16),'0x'+nvar,1)

SELECT *
FROM @test
```

Output:

```
nvar                                bin16
20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0    0x20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0
```

**Note**: there is more info about `CONVERT` and `style = 1` in a context of `binary` datatype [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles) on docs MS.

Comment: Also It Can Be Done Like This : DECLARE @bin BINARY(16)
DECLARE valString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET valString = N'20E60E0175D4F44CD6F7947883DDD4D0'
SET bin = CONVERT(binary(16),'0x'+valString,1)
SELECT bin

Comment: My pleasure! If my answer was useful feel free to upvote/accept it!

Comment: It is quiet same way I introduced in my answer :) Good luck!

Comment: yes It Is But In My Query I Cant Define Temporary Table I Wrote It For Someone Like Myself tnks Again And Good Luck :)